# (Java) sequence of execution

Tags: java

my i got a problem on the sequence of my code...

here it is.

```
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    enemy.setNewLife(j);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    enemy.setNewLife(j);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    enemy.setNewLife(j);
                    break;

            }

                switch (n) {
                    case 0:
                        player.setGun1();
                        enemy[j] = 
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        player.setGun2();
                        break;
                }
```

so the enemyship has a life of 10.
then the gun power has 4

enemyshipLife -= gunpower

1st shot enemyLife = 6; boolean dead = false;

2nd shot enemyLife = 2; boolean dead = false;

3rd shot enemyLife = -2; boolean dead = true;

my gun wont get the points... coz my code executed the setNewLife... therefore changing the boolean to true........

i tried swapping the position of switch (n) and if (enemyLife[j] <= 0 && dead[j] == false)... but my gun still not getting the points.... if the gun power is = 5... the gun gets the proper points..

any idea?

i just thought... how come my gun2 gets the point.? if the reason is because setNewLife is executed first.. then my gun2 wont get the points either??? now this becomes more weird...

Comment: java or javascript?  I'm confused. and please format this better.

Comment: Looks to be Java, but it's tagged as `javascript`. OP, please correct the tag (or the title).

Comment: Code is a little messy, can you update the formatting?

Comment: corrected. my bad, please don't put the -1 =.="  im also confused... total beginner here... sorry!    code format fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some serious issues on understanding OO.  You are putting variables inside arrays and some in objects.  You should put everything inside the objects (eg. Enemy, Gun, Player).

Take for example:

```
enemy1.setNewLife(enemyLife[j]);
```

and

```
if (enemyLife[j] <= 0 && dead[j] == false)
```

since enemy1 (Object), enemyLife[], and dead[] (Array) are obviously related, you should put them in the same place:

```
public class Enemy {
    protected int lifeScore;
    protected boolean dead;
    protected in position;
    //.. add constructor, getters
}
```

and then you can access them in an array of Enemy-s.

```
Enemy [] enemy = new Enemy[3];
enemy[0] = new Enemy();
enemy[1] = new Enemy();
enemy[2] = new Enemy();

enemy[0].adjustLife(int someDelta); // to adjust the life of this enemy
enemy[0].getLife(); // to get the life points
enemy[0].isDead(); // to check if it's dead
enemy[0].getPosition(); // to retrieve the position
```

Comment: i agree with you.... but my teacher made the skeleton... and it was made that way... i got 5 class.. one for playership, enemyship, global(for keyboard input), game and gun....

the gun1 and gun2 object was made in player class...

then enemy1,2,3 in Game class


also, the lifescore, boolean is placed on enemy class... 

then position in playership, enemyship and gun class.. they all got private int position.....


i think it is better termed as initialize? when i do "enemy[1] = new Enemy();" its called initialize right? or create object?

Comment: but how is setNewLife related to enemyLife?  If you do not tie them together, enemyLife will not change.  You could try and pass setNewLife(enemyLife) and change the array index.

Comment: idk how im doing it but when i call enemy1.setNewLife(inputting here the value of the (enemy1 - gunPower)

then the setNewLife that is in class enemy,, that also has the int Life= the new value

then i change the boolean status if its 0 or negative

Comment: can i ask for a private email ergonaut.. so i can send my full code...? thank you!  this is just really confusing...

Comment: then you should use: if (enemy[j].getLife() <= 0 && enemy[j].getDead() == false) {

Comment: Break down your problem, and don't do everything at once.  Debug or use print statements to see what's going on at every step.

Comment: ok. thanks ill do that...but. if the game Class creates the objects enemy1,2,3, and playership then the PlayerShip class creates the object gun1 and gun2..   (((how do i use something like gun1.getPower   in Game class))) i get past this problem by doing ((int gun1Power = player.getgun1Power))  then i use the gun1power in the Class Game.

Comment: In Game class, player1.getGun().getPower() is perfectly fine if it is visible.

Comment: what would be in the getGun() method???  im really sorry.. this is so hard for me to understand anymore.. sigh....